# Problems about creating tables

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow, nicematrix, makecell

I want to create a table like this[image]

However, what I can get is one like this[image]

In the table I created, there are two problems existing, which are

1. the middle vertical line is too short to reach the top or bottom horizontal lines;
2. the position of the text in the second row is so high that the text touches the horizontal line above.

Can you help me correct the two problems?

The following is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,makecell,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering\scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc|cccc}
        \toprule
        \multirowcell{2}{$\beta$} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{The first stage (DeepLabV3+)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{The second stage (DeepLabV3+)} \\ \Xcline{2-9}{0.05em}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{IoU/ \%} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{CPA/ \%} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{IoU/ \%} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{CPA/ \%} \\ \midrule
        & Background & Leaf & Background & Leaf & Background & Disease &Background & Disease \\ \Xcline{1-9}{0.05em}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcom to TeX SX! Use `\caption{…} ` for the first line with the table number. For the problem with the vertical rules, don't use the rules from `booktags` as they have some vertical padding. As to cell texts touching the horizontal rules, you should take a look at the `cellspace` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses the package `nicematrix`.

The `\Block{nrows-ncols}{<content>}` command acts as a multi-row/multi-column combination, centering the content.

[image: c]

Added optional `cell-space-limits` parameter to second table, to expand the cells vertically and deleting the (now superfluous) vertical line.

[image: e]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{% caption set up
    format=hang, 
    font=small,
    aboveskip=1ex,
    singlelinecheck=false
}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering\scriptsize
    \caption{The results of varying $\beta$  for Adaptive loss (based on DeepLabV3+ with movilenetv2 as the backbone)}  
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c cccc|cccc}    
        \toprule         
        \Block{3-1}{$\beta$}& \Block{1-4}{The first stage (DeepLabV3+)}
        &   &   &           & \Block{1-4}{The second stage (DeepLabV3+)} 
        &   &   &                           \\ 
        \cmidrule(lr{1ex}){2-5}\cmidrule(lr{1ex}){6-9}
            & \Block{1-2}{IoU/\%}       &           &  \Block{1-2}{CPA/\%} &
            & \Block{1-2}{IoU/\%}       &           &  \Block{1-2}{CPA/\%}    \\ 
        \cmidrule(lr{1ex}){2-3} \cmidrule(lr{1ex}){4-5}
        \cmidrule(lr{1ex}){6-7} \cmidrule(lr{1ex}){8-9}
            & Background    & Leaf      & Background& Leaf 
            & Background    & Disease   & Background& Disease      \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \centering\scriptsize
    \caption{The results of varying $\beta$  for Adaptive loss (based on DeepLabV3+ with movilenetv2 as the backbone)}
    \NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=2pt}   % expand the cells
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c cccc cccc}
        \toprule         
        \Block{3-1}{$\beta$}& \Block{1-4}{The first stage (DeepLabV3+)}
        &   &   &           & \Block{1-4}{The second stage (DeepLabV3+)} 
        &   &   &                           \\ 
        \cmidrule(lr{1ex}){2-5}\cmidrule(lr{1ex}){6-9}
        &\Block{1-2}{IoU/\%}        &           &  \Block{1-2}{CPA/\%} &
        & \Block{1-2}{IoU/\%}       &           &  \Block{1-2}{CPA/\%}    \\ 
        \cmidrule(lr{1ex}){2-3} \cmidrule(lr{1ex}){4-5}
        \cmidrule(lr{1ex}){6-7} \cmidrule(lr{1ex}){8-9}
        & Background    & Leaf      & Background& Leaf 
        & Background    & Disease   & Background& Disease      \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document
```

Answer (score 2):

- Your problems can be solved width use of the `tabularray` package
- Two cases of your table design:

  - Without vertical line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering\scriptsize
    \begin{tblr}{colsep = 3pt,
                 colspec= {@{} c cccc cccc @{}},
                 }
        \toprule
\SetCell[r=3]{m}    $\beta$
    & \SetCell[c=4]{c}  The first stage (DeepLabV3+)
        &   &   &   & \SetCell[c=4]{c}  The second stage (DeepLabV3+)   
                        &   &   &                           \\ 
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-5}
    \cmidrule[l ]{6-9}
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  IoU/ \%
        &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  CPA/ \%
                &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  IoU/ \%
                        &   &  \SetCell[c=2]{c}  CPA/ \%    \\ 
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-3}\cmidrule[lr]{4-5}
    \cmidrule[lr]{6-7}\cmidrule[l]{8-9}
    & Background    & Leaf      & Background & Leaf 
    & Background    & Disease   & Background & Disease      \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- With vertical line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering\scriptsize
    \begin{tblr}{colsep = 3pt,
                 colspec= {@{} c cccc|cccc @{}},
                 }
        \toprule
\SetCell[r=3]{m}    $\beta$
    & \SetCell[c=4]{c}  The first stage (DeepLabV3+)
        &   &   &   & \SetCell[c=4]{c}  The second stage (DeepLabV3+)   
                        &   &   &                           \\ 
    \midrule[gray]
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  IoU/ \%
        &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  CPA/ \%
                &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  IoU/ \%
                        &   &  \SetCell[c=2]{c}  CPA/ \%    \\ 
    \midrule
    & Background    & Leaf      & Background & Leaf 
    & Background    & Disease   & Background & Disease      \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]